Have certain screens still display BottomTabs which might be opened from screens without BottomTabs
My react app has bottom navigation tabs but contains certain screens (ex. chat screen) which takes up the full screen. I would like to have have certain screens that still display the bottom navigation tabs.
In my code I have a ConversationsScreen which displays all conversations. When the user clicks one of the items it takes them to a ChatScreen which takes up the full screen to allow easy messaging. I would like to allow the user to view details from the ChatScreen which takes them to the CommunityScreen but would like to have the CommunityScreen still display the active Bottom Tab in case the user wants to return back to the main ConversationsScreen without having to go back twice on the app.
const StackNavigator = () => {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  const { isLoading, token } = useContext(AuthContext);
  function BottomTabs() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{ tabBarShowLabel: false }}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarStyle: styles.tabBarStyle,
            tabBarLabelStyle: styles.tabBarLabelStyle,
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) =>
              focused ? (
                <EvilIcons name="spinner-2" size={35} color="white" />
              ) : (
                <EvilIcons name="spinner-2" size={35} color="#989898" />
              ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Matches"
          component={MatchesScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarStyle: styles.tabBarStyle,
            tabBarLabelStyle: styles.tabBarLabelStyle,
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) =>
              focused ? (
                <MaterialIcons name="handshake" size={35} color="white" />
              ) : (
                <MaterialIcons name="handshake" size={35} color="#989898" />
              ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Conversations"
          component={ConversationsScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarStyle: styles.tabBarStyle,
            tabBarLabelStyle: styles.tabBarLabelStyle,
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) =>
              focused ? (
                <Ionicons name="chatbubbles-outline" size={35} color="white" />
              ) : (
                <Ionicons
                  name="chatbubbles-outline"
                  size={35}
                  color="#989898"
                />
              ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={ProfileScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarStyle: styles.tabBarStyle,
            tabBarLabelStyle: styles.tabBarLabelStyle,
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) =>
              focused ? (
                <EvilIcons name="user" size={35} color="white" />
              ) : (
                <EvilIcons name="user" size={35} color="#989898" />
              ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
  }

function MainStack() {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Main"
          component={BottomTabs}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Community" component={CommunityScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {token === null || token === "" ? <AuthStack /> : <MainStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};



You can embed the CommunityScreen within the BottomTabs instead of the MainStack. This way, the bottom tabs will still be visible when navigating to the CommunityScreen from the ChatScreen.
You can conditionally render the CommunityScreen within the BottomTabs based on a parameter or state, ensuring it's only accessible from the ChatScreen
